# How to align text without two column?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, vertical-alignment

I want to have the following text alignment and I don't want to use any "two column" and table because an environment I use doesn't support them. :(

The text format looks like the picture below. Basically I want to split a line in the  middle, and for a line of text there will be 2 parts: the 1st part is on the left and the 2nd part is on the right. However, there are some lines which have long text and I don't want to split them to two parts, thus they will not split.

Thanks a lot for help!

[image]

Comment: Take a look into the `tabbing` environment.

Comment: What do you mean by "the environment I use doesn't support them"? Any LaTeX system supports the `tabular` environment.

Comment: It's a non-official package which support traditional chineses note (known as warichu). The package can be found here: http://code.google.com/p/gezhu/.

Comment: It looks **tabbing** environment also not support. :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a command that manually puts its first argument into the "left column" and the second argument into the "right column.

[image: output]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\leftright[2]{%
  \leavevmode
  \rlap{#1}%
  \hspace{0.5\linewidth}%
  #2}
\begin{document}
\leftright{first line part 1}{first line part 2} \par
A longer line that isn't split in two columns \par
\leftright{third line part 1}{third line part 2}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Though I can't directly use your solution, but this inspire me. :) I have solve this by only apply this changes to main contents.